# Filter column value by the first character?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is what I've done so far.

```
$filtered_results = array();

$result = $this->db
               ->select('name')
               ->from('user')
               ->get()
               ->result_array();    

foreach($result as $name)
{
    if($name[0]=='a')
    {
        filtered_results[] = $name;
    }
}
```

The above code logically wastes too much time processing all the results if my table contains tons of rows. So, the other way around is to directly retrieve only results with `'a'` as their `$name[0];`. Is this possible?

```
->where('name'.[0],'a')
```

Comment: `... WHERE LEFT(name, 1) = 'a'`?

Comment: Please fix the question. It's not the column name, but the column value

Comment: I have a column name in my table where i got the results. The $name is from the foreach, showing retrieved results as $name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be a start:

Example1:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `user` where `name` like 'a%'
```

Example2: (Marc B)

```
SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE LEFT(`name`, 1) = 'a'
```

Comment: does 'a%' mean that the first character is a and % is the rest chars of the string.

Comment: @user3205047, Yes, buth i would suggest you what Marc B wrote, I would add it.

Comment: yes. `%`is a wildcard. a% means "startswith a" or "%a" means endswith. And '%a%' means contains ...

Comment: Both are what im looking for,  although might i ask, which is better. Or if which is faster in terms of querying. i need to minimize loadtime as much as possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I needed a filter by first letter for an app using WebSQL database... the 'a%' option works good but the Marc B throws an error... so in case someone will used WebSQL, the first option is the one to choose...